# A Regex to match text that starts with a space and ends with a know value

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a string on a multiline text using Regex, the string looks something similar to this:
`space-separated-values 1/2/tmp/known_text\n`

I'm trying to match `1/2/tmp/` **i.e** everything that comes after the last whitespace up until the known_text value I have, everything in between is unknown to me.
I've tried a lot on https://regex101.com/ but couldn't get to figure it out, could anyone help me doing that please!

Comment: Is there no space after known text? Or could there be some more space?

Comment: there's a line and after the know text

Comment: Provide some proper example strings

Comment: k d kn tmp/myfolder1/1.png  
s a mm tmp/myfolder1/1.png

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Comment: I'm using Elixir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find a space, then no spaces until `knownvalue`:

```
\s[^\s]*knownvalue\n
```

I have a fiddle here: https://regex101.com/r/qRj0Qi/2.

Comment: it's exactly what I was aiming for, except I removed the `\s` at the begging
thanx a lot!